# Pascal's triangle with loops and conditioning

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

How to make Pascal's triangle in JavaScript using repetition and conditioning without using arrays and functions

```
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

I tried code like this and the results were correct

```js
let s = '';
for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){

    for(let space = 1; space <= 5 - baris; space++){
        s += ' ';
    }

    for (let j = 1; j <= i; digit++){        
        if(j === 1 || j === i){
            s += 1 + ' ';
        } else if (j === 3 && i === 5) {
            s += j + j + ' ';
        }
        else {
            s += i - 1 + ' '
        }
    }
    s += '\n';
}
console.log(s);
```

however when I change the number of rows it gets messed up
Is it possible to create Pascal's triangle just with loops and conditioning without functions and arrays?
I've tried and looked for solutions everywhere but they all use functions and arrays

Comment: The code shown is producing an error because a variable isn't defined.  You also indicate that the code shown works as expected?  Please update the question to clarify what you are asking and what specifically isn't working as expected in the code you're showing us.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself

```js
const rows = 7;
for (let n=0; n<rows; n++) {
    let s = '';
    let p = 1;
    for (let k=1; k<=n+1; k++) {
        s += '' + p + ' ';
        p = p * (n + 1 - k) / k;
    }
    console.log(s);
}
```

Comment: thank you sir for helping me